# Saving multiple documents per seconds on MongoDB returns timeout

Tags: node.js, arrays, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I am trying to map through an array [of nearly 1200 objects] with the Javascript's `.map()` method to individually save each object to a Mongodb database (enriched with extra data).
The first 270 or so would get saved without problems to Mongodb. But subsequent attempts to save would resolve in this error:

```
    Request failed:  Error: Timeout of 60000ms exceeded
    at RequestBase._timeoutError (/home/i8mi/Desktop/work/projects/s/mailer/node_modules/superagent/lib/request-base.js:722:13)
    at Timeout.<anonymous> (/home/i8mi/Desktop/work/projects/s/mailer/node_modules/superagent/lib/request-base.js:736:12)
    at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:554:17)
    at processTimers (internal/timers.js:497:7) {
  timeout: 60000,
  code: 'ECONNABORTED',
  errno: 'ETIME',
  response: undefined
}
```

The whole operation ends in less than 2 minutes - the successful saves and the failures.

I understand this is a timeout error from nodejs(superagent) error. I can't seem to find any information on rate limits for mongoDB cloud.

At the end there would be erros like these:

```
(node:13061) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoNetworkTimeoutError: connection timed out
    at connectionFailureError (/home/i8mi/Desktop/work/projects/s/mailer/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connect.js:342:14)
    at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (/home/i8mi/Desktop/work/projects/s/mailer/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connect.js:310:16)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:420:28)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:314:20)
    at TLSSocket.Socket._onTimeout (net.js:484:8)
    at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:554:17)
    at processTimers (internal/timers.js:497:7)
```

Any idea what could possibly be done to solve this? Do I need something like Redis, Kafka or RabbitMQ for this?

Stack versions:

> ```
> - Node v12.19.1
> - Mongoose: "^5.12.2",
> - Database: MongoDB Cloud (free tier)
> ```

**Update:**

Actual code:

```
    function GetRequestResourceIds(data){
    console.log(data[0].tagList)
    TagList.find({_id: data[0].tagList}, (err, result) => {
        console.log(result)
        return new Promise(async(resolve, reject) => {
            if(!err && result){
                // Now create mxLead for each person in this Tag List
                     // find the greeting info to use
                const allRecipients = result[0].jsonList
                // console.log(result)
               await Greeting.find({_id: data.greeting}, (err, result) => {
                    if(!err && result){
                        // do this for each person in the list
                        const avartarGreeting = result.avartarGreeting
                        const initialTextGreeting = result.textGreeting
                        allRecipients.map(async(recipient) => {
                            //construct recipient (baseRecipient) data here
                            const baseRecipient = {
                                firstName: recipient.data[0],
                                lastName: recipient.data[1],
                                emailAddress: recipient.data[2],
                                avartarUrl: recipient.data[3],
                            }
                            // const textGreeting = initialTextGreeting+baseRecipient.firstName
                            const textGreeting = initialTextGreeting
                            const avData = {
                                avartarGreeting,
                                textGreeting,
                                avartarUrl: baseRecipient.avartarUrl,
                            }
                            
                            return personalizedAvatar.personalizedAvatar(avData)
                                    .then(newAvatar => {
                                      const newAvatars = new Avatar({
                                            recipientEmail: baseRecipient.emailAddress,
                                            recipientFirstName: baseRecipient.firstName,
                                            recipientLastName: baseRecipient.lastName,
                                            newAvatar,
                                            status: "done",
                                        })
                                        newAvatars.save()
                                       // console.log("success")
                                        resolve('success')
                                    })
                        })
                        
                    }
                })
                // return result
            } 
            else {
                console.log("failed")
                resolve("failed")
            }
        })
    })
}

module.exports.GetRequestResourceIds = GetRequestResourceIds
```

This is intended for a use case where game developers can generate avatars for players automatically as they achieve ranks, join a group or just for seasonal greetings. So they could be sending an array of one, hundreds or thousands users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your error's stack trace does not mention MongoDB at any point. `superagent` is an HTTP client, which has nothing to do with MongoDB - so that timeout is coming from somewhere else.

The second error, which I suppose comes from the actual piece of code that does the writing, indicates a connection timeout - either when attempting to connect (are you establishing a new connection for each write?) or when writing the documents due to connection starvation. In either case, you are probably suffering from *unbounded concurrency* - a condition where arbitrarily many asynchronous operations are executing at the same time (read more: [Promise.allpocalypse](https://eng.lifion.com/promise-allpocalypse-cfb6741298a7)) - though I cannot be sure without seeing some code.

When writing large numbers of documents to MongoDB, you should probably be using `collection.insertMany` (see code: [MongoDB usage examples](https://docs.mongodb.com/drivers/node/usage-examples/insertMany/)), which enables you to pass whole arrays of documents to save.

You do not need a message queue for writing large numbers of documents to MongoDB, unless each of them requires special processing by workers.

EDIT: Based on the now-included code, here are some possible improvements:

- Iterate over the recipient list first, compute everything you need and store in some variable
- Save the new documents in bulk - here, we assume they're all new, so `insertMany` should do
- Handle all promises in a way that doesn't lose rejections (.catch())
- Avoid mixing new Promise(), .then() and async functions - settle on one style, preferably async/await if possible (this lets you avoid .catch() and just do `try {} catch ()` instead)
- Do not resolve with "failure" if an error occurs - that's what exceptions and `throw` are for

Comment: Hey Robert, here is a gist for the actual code https://gist.github.com/Zonalds/189cea0af516095bacd2fd66efea6ec8. I am building an API that allows developers to generate custom avatars everyday. So they can send thousands of users per day.

What do you think I ought to change.
I will update the question to include the actual code.

Comment: See updated recommentations based on the code gist.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have implemented the suggested improvements - works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

The way you are trying to accomplish this task doesn't sound healthy or db/network-friendly. You should rather research and implement mongoDb [bulkWrite](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/bulk-write-operations/) operations - or at the very least find a way of using insertMany(), updateMany(), or any of its peers.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably making too many requests for execution, try to put code inside foreach and execute one request at a time.

```
jobs.forEach(a => {mongoose.set("strictQuery", false);
            mongoose.connect('your string')
            .then(()=> {
                const job = new Job({
                    _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),                   
                    title: a.title,
                    location: a.location,
                  });            
                job
                .save()                
                .catch(err => {
                    console.log(err);                
                });
            });
        });
```

The example above is my code, so see that just as the inspiration :)